# Terminating a Substitution Variable Name in PL/SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to write a query that has text immediately following a substitution variable.  I know it can be done in SQL Plus but I'm not sure if it is possible in PL/SQL Developer without using dynamic SQL.  As a simple example, I create this table with test data:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE AS
SELECT 1 AS COL_1 FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 1.1 AS COL_1 FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 11 AS COL_1 FROM DUAL
```

From what I've read, the end of a substitution variable is indicated by a period (.).  However, this only seems to work correctly in SQL Plus.

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE
  2  WHERE COL_1 = &SUB_VAR.1;
     COL_1
----------
        11
```

When I run the above query and enter `1` when prompted for the value of `SUB_VAR`, I get `11` returned as desired.

However, when I run the same query in a SQL window in PL/SQL Developer, I get `1.1` returned instead, which shows that it is treating the period as a decimal point instead.

Is there a way to replicate the same behavior in a SQL window in PL/SQL Developer as in SQL Plus?

Comment: SQL Developer (not the product you are using) has two modes: "query" mode (with its own environment) and "script" mode. I assume PL/SQL Developer does too. Did you try the query in "script" mode? That should be much closer to SQL\*Plus.

Comment: I’ll look into that.  I wasn’t aware of an option to change the mode in PL/SQL Developer, but if there is it sounds like it could work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  All I needed to do was wrap the substitution variable name in double quotes.

```
SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE
WHERE COL_1 = &"SUB_VAR"1
```

Answer (score 1):

That would be concatenation, along with possible datatype conversion (`TO_NUMBER`, `TO_CHAR`, `CAST` etc.).

This is what I meant:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from test_table
  3  where col_1 = to_number(&sub_var || '1');
Enter value for sub_var: 1

     COL_1
----------
        11

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you.  That does work, although I need to be able to do it without using the concatenation operator due to some more complex use cases I have.  Sorry for not specifying that in the question.

Comment: That is not a good practice. The substitution variable will return 1, for example, not '1'. So you are relying on an implicit conversion. If instead you wanted the substitution variable to return the string ABC and wanted to concatenate DE, you couldn't do this. (You would have to include single-quotes in the variable itself, another not-good practice.)

Comment: You're welcome. Though, I'm with @mathguy here. The fact that you can do that (somehow), doesn't mean that you should do it. If you want to get `11` as a result, why wouldn't you simply pass `11` as the parameter value, without using some *tricks*?

Comment: Yeah I agree in practice with this simple example you would just pass `11`.  For my more complex use cases I need to be able to concatenate without using the concatenation operator but instead indicating when the substitution variable terminates like in SQL Plus.  It may not be possible in PL/SQL Developer though.